# Permission denied - /mnt/foo/releases/20130607190757/public/uploads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, carrierwave

Locally everything works as expected, I use the :file storage and it is working.

But my deployed version uses the :fog storage and it is not working. Everytime that i try to upload a image there I face the following error:

```
Permission denied - /mnt/foo/releases/20130607190757/public/uploads
```

My uploader configuration is the following:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
```

And my initializer is defined as following:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|

  unless Rails.env.test?
    config.fog_credentials = {
      :provider               => 'AWS',
      :aws_access_key_id      => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      :aws_secret_access_key  => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    }
    config.fog_directory = Rails.configuration.fog_directory
    config.fog_public     = false
  end

  if Rails.env.test? or Rails.env.cucumber?
    config.enable_processing = false
    config.storage = :file

  # We may want to changes storage to 'file' after initial testing
  elsif Rails.env.development?
    config.storage = :file

  elsif Rails.env.staging? or Rails.env.pilot? or Rails.env.production?
    config.storage = :fog
  end

end
```

Anyone knows what can be causing that error? It looks like it is storing as a file, since it shows the whole file's path.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the problem is that I was not creating the folder during the rubber deployment. After creating the folder I was able to finish my deployment.

Answer (score 0):

try to extend the rights to this folder